# Euler Characteristic of MengerMesh

Tags: mesh, fractals, topology

When I ask Mathematica to give me the Euler characteristic of `MengerMesh[1, 3]`, it returns 16. It seems to me the 1-step Menger sponge has genus 5 and should therefore have Euler characteristic -8. For `MengerMesh[2, 3]`, I'm again off by a factor of -2, as Mathematica returns 320 while I predict -160 based on its genus, which is 81. For `MengerMesh[0, 3]`, me and Mathematica agree.

Can anyone please explain to me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MengerMesh` returns a full dimensional mesh, e.g. in 3D a solid, not a surface.

```
mr = MengerMesh[2, 3];

RegionDimension[mr]
```

> ```
> 3
> ```

```
MeshCellCount[mr]
```

> ```
> {896, 2304, 1728, 400}
> ```

We can instead find the characteristic of its boundary:

```
EulerCharacteristic[mr]
```

> ```
> 320
> ```

```
EulerCharacteristic[RegionBoundary[mr]]
```

> ```
> -160
> ```

Comment: Yea, of course.